# Push page up on content load

Tags: html, wordpress

This is my first post here. I am working in Wordpress trying to customize it to reach my clients needs.

I have a tab section which i need to enable a click to show and hide the content but also when it opens to show the content it pushes the page up to reveal all content, currently it gets lost behind my sticky footer. I belive it pushed content down below but i need it to lift up and reveal.

I am currently tweaking the page design but hopefully you can get a visual.

Any help would be great.

http://alvarodelaherran.com/boxell/works/mine/

Regards

Patrick

Comment: please add here the relevant code related to your issue.

Comment: Hi, I have this code which you can see on the link above opens the tabs in the format i need. But i need to tweak so it closes just as smoothly.

Comment: the js code is too long to post here, how should i show it?